# C# How can i detect crud operations in each Microservice API and publish them to rabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq, microservices

I want when a crud operation is executed in let's say an ADMIN microservice API, rabbitMQ to catch the event and publish the crud operation as a message and then from the other side to consume the message with a service or some tool and then use it to update another database?
How can this be done?

Comment: That's a little bit squishy. What exactly do you mean by "detect" and "catch the Event"?

Comment: I mean I want to continuously sync the database of the microservice to another database. Each time data is changed in the microservice database to be synced with the other database. This is the concept. But I am not sure of how exactly to do it.

Comment: did you think to use trigger after insert,update,delete?

Comment: That trigger to publish the message to rabbitMQ with the query of the executed action ?
I have never done that so I am searching for a way to do code-first method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of CDC(Change Capture Detection). So one of your Microservices can as usual make changes to the Database( CRUD operations).

So there is something called Debezium and Kafka combination that actually can stream these DB changes. Debezium takes care of reading CDC events and publishing them to Kafka and you can consume these DB changes(JSON format) from Kafka.

For example, Microservice 1 inserted a record and then updated it, and finally deleted that record.

So If you configure Debezium to read these events, It reads all these events sequentially and then publishes them to Kafka( It also supports Kinesis, Pubsub) but no support to Rabbit MQ directly

Debezium supports most of the databases.
Here is an example on how I am doing this with Kinesis and Mysql
https://xyzcoder.github.io/2021/02/19/cdc-using-debezium-server-mysql-kinesis.html

Comment: Thanks. It does not look simple solution at all. :(

Comment: I am searching for now a way to push each crud operation from my service to the rabbitMQ. The problem is that how do I extract the query form the database to be stored in the rabbitMQ as a message ?

Comment: If you use inline queries and not an ORM, then you can send the same query to RabbitMQ. But if you are using an ORM may be you can try to extract that query as a raw query and send it. But this doesn't actually work out in real time. In case if you have a stored procedure which does lot of crud operations you'll not be able to do exact same thing on the other side.

Comment: Also You should be careful with RabbitMQ. If you have more subscribers(Many Microservices consuming) and using Queuing feature. Then there is a chance that this message is not delivered to all Microservices. And also you cannot guarantee to order and that will be a problem.
For example, You have an insert, update statement and delete statement on a record.
And If they are not processed in the same order on the consumer side, You'll get data inconsistencies.

Comment: Is there an easy way to constantly sync two databases on each change (update/delete/insert)?

Comment: I wrote an article on how to do this
https://xyzcoder.github.io/2021/02/19/cdc-using-debezium-server-mysql-kinesis.html